# The quantity is not deleted correctly within the store

Tags: php, laravel

My problem completely is that when any customer purchases an electronic card from the store, the quantity of the card is deleted correctly. The problem is when he purchases a quantity of the card, for example 3 cards. Also, the quantity is deducted from the card with a value of only 1.
Although I made a loop in the code, but it is not working properly

```
        foreach ($cart->items as $key => $prod) {
    if (!empty($prod['item']['license']) && !empty($prod['item']['license_qty'])) {
                       $orderedQty = $prod['qty'];

        foreach ($prod['item']['license_qty'] as $ttl => $dtl) {
                $orderedQty = $prod['qty'];
                 for ($i = 0; $i < $orderedQty ; $i++) {
                if ($dtl != 0) {
                    $dtl--;
                    $produc = Product::findOrFail($prod['item']['id']);
                    $temp = $produc->license_qty;
                    $temp[$ttl] = $dtl;
                    $final = implode(',', $temp);
                    $produc->license_qty = $final;
                    $produc->update();
                    $temp = $produc->license;
                    $license =  array_slice($temp, 0, $orderedQty);
                    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
                    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
                    $cart->updateLicense($prod['item']['id'], $license);
                    Session::put('cart', $cart);
                    break;
                
               

             }
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As shown in the picture, it is assumed that by my code, the value of license_qty is checked, if it is zero, it checks the next value until it finds that it is not equal to zero

And he subtracts 1 from the value he finds. The problem is that it does not work, since I added a loop based on the quantity of the product from the cart.